# Get rid of extra horizontal space between words in bibliography

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, natbib, white-space

There is additional horizontal whitespace between words in my bibliography entries. I assume latex does this to align line breaks. But this whitespace is too large. I want to remove the extra whitespace between these words, and I don't mind if because of that the line breaks are not completely aligned. Does anyone know how to do this? I am using natbib with bibliographystyle plainnat.

[image]

Comment: you could use `\raggedright` but something is very non standard and very wrong to get the output that you show. What is stopping latex put Berkowitz on the first line?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! As David says this does not look like standard behaviour.  Please provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) demonstrating - I suspect you will only need the one bibliography item...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting \setcitestyle{numbers}. I am not entirely sure yet why this caused the weird line breaks, but this solves it.